# Groovyscript grails system commands

Tags: grails, groovy, scripting, system, command

Is there a possibility of running my "grails run-app" command from my groovy script? I tried "cmd /c dir".execute() and it was working but "cmd /c grails run-app" doesn't seem to work :( Can anybody help me? I dont know how to see the output too :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the best way of doing this is not via the system command line.

The grails commands are actually Groovy scripts with the prefix "_Grails" and found in the `scripts` directory of the Grails installation. You should be able to run those Groovy scripts programmatically from your code without going through the command line, but I am not sure what's the best way to get at them.